# Extending Umbraco ProfileModel with custom member model

Tags: asp.net-membership, umbraco, umbraco7

I have the following code while updating the member account detail information:

```
/// <summary>
/// Verifies and edits the member fields.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model"></param>
/// <returns>MemberDetailsFormViewModel containing all the editable information.</returns>
[Authorize]
public ActionResult HandleUpdateMemberDetails(MemberDetailsFormViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        }

        var memberService = Services.MemberService;
        var member = memberService.GetById(Members.GetCurrentMemberId());

        member.Properties[Constant.PropertyAlias.Authentication.FirstName].Value    = model.FirstName;
        member.Properties[Constant.PropertyAlias.Authentication.LastName].Value     = model.LastName;
        member.Properties[Constant.PropertyAlias.Authentication.AddressLine1].Value = model.AddressLine1;
        member.Properties[Constant.PropertyAlias.Authentication.AddressLine2].Value = model.AddressLine2;
        member.Properties[Constant.PropertyAlias.Authentication.TownCity].Value     = model.TownCity;
        member.Properties[Constant.PropertyAlias.Authentication.PostCode].Value     = model.PostCode;
        member.Properties[Constant.PropertyAlias.Authentication.County].Value       = model.County;
        member.Properties[Constant.PropertyAlias.Authentication.Country].Value      = model.Country;
        member.Properties[Constant.PropertyAlias.Authentication.PhoneNumber].Value  = model.PhoneNumber;

        memberService.Save(member);

        if (Members.IsLoggedIn())
        {
            ViewBag.DetailSuccessfullyChanged = 1;
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        }

        return View("/");
}
```

Although this solution works, I would like to do more *elegant* updating of the `member.Properties["propertyName"].Value` through extended `ProfileModel` with the following method of `MembershipHelper`: `UpdateMemberProfile(ProfileModel model)`.

Useful links:

- `MembershipHelper` [documentation link](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/MemberShipHelper/).
- [Similar issue on OUR Umbraco](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/52706-U7-adding-custom-member-properties-to-the-ProfileModel)

Has anyone managed to do something like this?

**EDIT**:

I see that Warren did [something similiar](https://github.com/warrenbuckley/CWS-Umbraco-Standard-Membership/blob/master/CWSUmbracoStandardMembership/Controllers/SurfaceControllers/ProfileSurfaceController.cs#L49-L74) on his GitHub.